# Best practice for AJAX long polling if I do not have a Timestamp

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a page that uses AJAX to show or hide a message set by the admin in my backend. So I used AJAX to see if that message should be shown. On the page I I had

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        getmessage();
    });
function getData() {    
        $.ajax({ 
                type: "GET",
                url: "./ajax/getMessage.php",                           
                success: function(response){ 
                    if (response != "") {
                        // show message
                    } else {
                        // hide message
                    }
                    setTimeout(
                        getData,
                        15000
                    );
                }
            });
    };
```

and in my `getMessage.php`

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE display = 1");
$output = getmessage($stmt);
echo $output ['messageText'];

function getmessage($stmt) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $row;
}
```

That works great, but as it is an event site I can have up to 2000 users on my page and polling every 15 seconds is maybe not the best idea (especially because I also have a tracking script on the same page, which sends AJAX posts every couple of minutes). But how can I switch that to long polling to just get an update when the display state changes or another message is chosen? I tried putting a loop in my php

```
while($output['messageText'] == NULL) {
    sleep(10);
    $output = getmessage($stmt);
}
```

But that freezes my server and does not give me any data when the message just changes or display is set from 1 to 0. Somehow I'm stuck.

Comment: real-time messaging should be handled by websocket. https://developer.mozilla.org/th/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

Comment: @AnuratChapanond Either that, or incase he doesn't have a websocket server, he can use ajax polling...

Comment: The page is used on client servers for the time of the event. Mostly low budget shared hosting. So unfortunately I have no  control over any server technology beside php and mysql.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using [SSE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events).
which is basically like long polling, But using same php code you can also create long polling.

About the database, you should make a [lock](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html) for the table, which will make it accessible only after the lock is lifted, after it is, the query will return and the php script will deliver the message\event. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html

after the read - you can relock the table.

locking syntax:

after read:

```
LOCK TABLES messages WRITE;
```

after update:

```
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: This is a very interesting approach. I do not think I can use Lock, as the messages are user generated - so other scripts read and write quite a lot from this table. But I'll have a look into SSE.

Comment: @Torf You're still going to need some kind of "trigger" in the php code to know when a message comes, even when using SSE, I've used a file watcher once, and everytime a user uploaded a message, I would create a file in a certain place with the data needed about the message, that way I could notify all the users about the new message, the php code would block until the file was created\edited.